# Looking for calculate script without submit button without reloading

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I've seen several forms on webshops where you just change the amount of items you want, and it instantly changes the price. No reloading and no submit (or calculate) button.

I'm looking for something like that, but very simple.

```
Amount of pages: [textfield]
price: [answer]
```

That's all.
The code must take the input from the [textfield] and multiply it with a certain number (which I can change in the code). The result of that calculation should be presented at [answer].

I've been looking around on Google, but I can only find very difficult and big forms that use a submit button. And my php/ajax/javascript isn't good enough to write te code myself.
I know that there are several Submit forms on Stackoverflow, but I don't understand how I can edit them to do what I want it to do.

You don't have to make it look fancy, I've made a nice form to put the code in.
Obviously it has to work on every major browser.

Edit:
I've tried the code supplied by Khòi.

I've tried playing with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
$('#pages').change(function(ev){
var total = $('#pages').val() * 0.2;
$('#total').html((total).toFixed(2));
});?
</script>
</head>
<body>

Pages: <input type="text" name="pages" id="pages" />
<br/><br/>
Total: <span id="total">0.00</span>

</body>
</html>
```

But that doesn't work ??
I did download the Jquery file and put into the same folder as this page is.

Comment: So,you haven't tried anything at all?

Comment: Yes I did, but couldn't figure it out. Have tried several forms which didn't do what I wanted so I tried to make them do what I wanted.... But didn't work. I found a few others that worked, but not on every browser. And at the moment I've got a PHP script, which works... but it has the submit button AND it reloads to show the result.

I'm not very skilled with PHP/ajax/javascript etc.etc. So it's very hard for me to find something that I can edit so it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd advise you to learn some basic JQuery. Things like these can be done very efficently with JQuery and the learning curve isn't too steep.

I made you a fiddle to get you started:

http://jsfiddle.net/jRs3n/

Here is the full code for a single working HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<title>test</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pages').keyup(function(ev){
        var total = $('#pages').val() * 0.2;
        $('#total').html((total).toFixed(2));
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

Pages: <input type="text" name="pages" id="pages" />
<br/><br/>
Total: <span id="total">0.00</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! That allready looks awesome. I'll take up your advice. Seems worth it.

I really don't wanna sounds ungrateful. But is there an easy way to make it recalculate without having to click somewhere besides the textfield? So it allready calculates when you type, not when your done (I hope you know what I mean, I'm not very good at explaining myself).

Comment: Also changed from `.change()` event to `.keyup()` so it'll calculate when you type.

Comment: Khôi, you're a legend! Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to calculate without leaving the box you need to change the event from `change` to `keyup` this will allow you to update after each keypress on the specific field.

Comment: Dude.... that's a great trick :D. Now just figuring out how to put into a page. I don't know how to give you any points for your answer. But i'll "up" it. (i'm a bit new here....)

Comment: Also with doing something on `keyup` and change you may want to ensure that you are validating the data, otherwise you could get a NaN in the answer field.

Comment: @kwelch I wouldn't know how to validate the input. Is it difficult? Thanks for the edit Kristaps Karlsons but i still have to figure out how to put it into a html page (see beginpost).